# how to make communication with two different process in same computer?

Tags: c#, winforms

there is two separate processed running on same PC i want to communicate between this two process.
like pass some data from one process to other .

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# communication between processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443211/c-sharp-communication-between-processes)

Comment: Google "windows interprocess communications".

Comment: Or Bing "windows interprocess communication" , "DLL", "Windows communication foundation"

Comment: can you please give simple example of Google or Bing "windows interprocess communication" ?

Comment: Here is an example, I am not sure I understand we are just telling you to look it up http://tinyurl.com/l53mmwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WCF
```

[Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx)

In general you need to implement a client - server architecture and define interface endpoints to communicate between the process that acts as client and the server process.

The other way is to create a  Remotable Class
a dynamic library (DLL) so that the same remoted class can be referenced by both the client and the server.

The **server** will have to create instance of the remote class to be able to make sense of the object-oriented data you communicate, and can listen for example on a TCP channel.

e.g

```
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel( new TcpChannel( PORT_NUMBER) );       

RemotingServices.Marshal( your_remoted_class, "name_connection" );
```

Or for local use you can just use the [IpcServerChannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcserverchannel(v=vs.110).aspx) API

Now on **Client**
if you used TCP port to listen on for server

```
string remoted_url = "tcp://localhost:<your_port_number>/connection name";

remoted_object = (RemotedClass)RemotingServices.Connect

( typeof(RemotedClass), remoted_url );
```

The client can now call the public functions through remote_object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are little bit specific about technology, then I could narrow down my answer.

In a very generic note, these are ways to communicate between two processes.

1. Message communication through a common file.
2. Socket communication between two processes.
3. Mutex
4. Any intermediate service.

There are several other ways.